# IE 6, 7 hover works for all corners except right-bottom

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I want different menu items in different corners having a simple hover effect. Following code is working. But only right-bottom menu item is not giving proper effect in IE6 and IE7. Whats wrong?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neqb5/3/).

**CSS:**

```
.d
{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#b2b2b2;
    position:fixed !important;
    *position: absolute;
}

.da {position:absolute;}

#d1 {left:0; top:0;}
#d2 {right:0; top:0;}
#d3 {right:0; bottom:0;}
#d4 {left:0; bottom:0;}

#d1a {bottom:0; right:0;}
#d2a {bottom:0; left:0;}
#d3a {top:0; left:0;}
#d4a {top:0; right:0;}

#d1a:hover {right:-5px; bottom:-5px;}
#d2a:hover {bottom:-5px; left:-5px;}
#d3a:hover {top:-5px; left:-5px;}
#d4a:hover {top:-5px; right:-5px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="d" id="d1">
    <a class="da" href="#" id="d1a"><img src="images/contact.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="d" id="d2">
    <a class="da" href="#" id="d2a"><img src="images/contact.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="d" id="d3">
    <a class="da" href="#" id="d3a"><img src="images/contact.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="d" id="d4">
    <a class="da" href="#" id="d4a"><img src="images/contact.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any other `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` layers on your page that could be floating above the bottom right link by accident? Best way to find out is to add this to your css `* { border: 1px solid purple; }`. if a layer floats above it will block the hover effect.

Comment: thnx @pebbl, i learned a nice trick from u. but there is no other layer.. the code in question is the full code..

Comment: You'll probably need to post a URL showing the problem. If you don't have webspace, use http://jsfiddle.net/ fpr example.

Comment: ok @RoToRa i have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neqb5/3/)

Comment: Have you tried with positive position values? I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that IE had a harder time with negative values.

Comment: Yes @Calvin, I tried with positive position values too. But not working. I am not able to understand why there is problem with only bottom-right corner..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found following solutions for the problem:

1) to add `visibility:hidden` to `#d3a:hover` block

or

2) to add `margin-left:0%` to `#d3a:hover` block

both solutions will make the code running properly in IE6 and IE7. (Even it is working with IE5.5 too)

Answer (score 2):

IE6 and IE7 are having a hard time with the negative numbers for some reason on the BR.

Strangely enough, if you remove the #d3a {top:0; left:0} css rule, (That should be its default position anyway) the problem goes away. In fact, if you play with it...any value other than top:0, left:0 allows the browser to properly determine the hover position of the #d3a div.

Further experimentation with !important on the #d3a:hover rule will help support that this is not an issue with css applying correctly, but rather, with the browser's ability to render position correctly. (That is to say that the css style is applying...but having no effect.)

Comment: Thanks @purgatory101, I did the experiments you mentioned in your answer. It is right by removing #d3a {top:0; left:0;} css rule it starts working. But I got the idea that it is happening because of sticky bug of IE versions. And as a solution I found 2 workarounds that I have posted here in my answer. Thanks again for your deep research and explanation. :)